# Cleveref \namecrf and \labelcrf works not \cref

Tags: cleveref

I try to implement the cleveref package. In a specific test, it works well but in a wider real context, it does not.
It shows the "??" that means that it doesn't know how to print the \cref in the context where the \label is included. It shows no hyperref link either.
Strangely enough, it does print \namecref and \labelcref that constitutes \cref.
Sorry for such an unprecise context, but I look for clues to explore further.

Comment: What do you expect as answer? "You are doing something wrong"? The first step to explore such a problem is to describe it more precisely.

Comment: @Ulrike I am looking for advices like : "Check \usepackage{hyperref} is placed before \usepackage{cleveref}" "Check the place of the \label which should be within the section" "You can get the name of the counter by looking in the error message" etc.

Comment: sorry but but I won't waste my time for this. Create a minimal example that one can really debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared a MNWE and a MWE.
The only difference for the \cref to work is to have the Enumitem \newlist, \setlist, and the Cleveref \crefname placed BEFORE the \begin{document}.
It is still very strange that part of Cleveref, namely \nameref and \labelref, still worked and were not sensitive to misplaced \cref.